# How do I remove "Optional()" from object in an array

Tags: swift, cloudkit

So im using CloudKit and fetching all the data into an array as [StartDay], my StartDay class looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class StartDay {

var recordID: CKRecord.ID!
var wakeUp: String!
var sleptWell: String!
var dNN: String!
var created: String! {

    get { 
        return created
    }
}
}`
```

My function loads get an arraylist, which contains information received from the database. In my database it stands like this: "22.01.09:

```
    func checkIfButtonShouldBeEnabled(startDayList: [StartDay]){

    let startDayDates = startDayList.map{$0.created}

    for i in 0..<startDayDates.count {

        print(startDayDates)

    }

}`
```

OUTPUT:
Optional("22.01.2019")
Optional("22.01.2019")

I want to remove "Optional()", so it only says "22.01.2019", how can I do so?

UPDATE: FETCH FUNC

```
func loadStartDay() -> [StartDay]{

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "StartDay", predicate: predicate)
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    var startDays: [StartDay] = []
    operation.desiredKeys = ["wakeUp", "wellSlept", "dNN", "recordID", "createdDato"]

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord) in
        let newStartDay = StartDay()

        newStartDay.wakeUp = record.object(forKey: "wakeUP") as? String
        newStartDay.sleptWell = record.object(forKey: "sleptWell") as? String
        newStartDay.dNN = record.object(forKey: "dNN") as? String
        newStartDay.recordID = record.object(forKey: "recordID") as? CKRecord.ID
        newStartDay.created = record.object(forKey: "createdDato") as? String

        print(newStartDay.created)

        startDays.append(newStartDay)

    }
```

Comment: You should unwrap the optional first with something like: `for date in startDayDates { if let date = date { print(date) } }`. Btw you are printing the same array over and over in your code (instead of the element at `i` as you probably intended)...

Comment: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

Comment: This means that the object you tried to unwrap is not optional.

Comment: But why does it print out optional()? Can i be because i save it like that in cloudkit? or fetch it wrong in?

Comment: It shows "22.01.2019" in cloudkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **you** designed the database model **you exactly know** which record attributes always exist. Declaring class properties as implicit unwrapped optional as an alibi not to write an initializer is very bad practice.

Assuming every attribute in a record does have a value declare the properties as non-optional and write an initializer.

At least `created` and `recordID` are supposed to have always a value!

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class StartDay {

    var recordID: CKRecord.ID
    var wakeUp: String
    var sleptWell: String
    var dNN: String
    var created: String 

    init(record : CKRecord) {
        // recordID can be retrieved directly
        self.recordID = record.recordID
        self.wakeUp = record.object(forKey: "wakeUP") as! String
        self.sleptWell = record.object(forKey: "sleptWell") as! String
        self.dNN = record.object(forKey: "dNN") as! String
        self.created = record.object(forKey: "createdDato") as! String
    }
}
```

and create instances with

```
operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
    startDays.append(StartDay(record: record))
}
```

Now the `Optional` has gone.

```
print(startDayList.map{ $0.created })
```

Comment: I get an error on: self.recordID = record.object(forkey: "recordID") as! CKRecordID 
The error: 3: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Either assign **always** a value to `recordID` on CloudKit while creating the record (recommended) or declare this property as optional: `var recordID: CKRecord.ID?` and `self.recordID = record.object(forKey: "recordID") as? CKRecord.ID`

Comment: I have assigned the wrong value for "wakeUP", i should be "wakeUp". Thank you, it works smoothly now!

Comment: I updated the answer. You can get the unique non-optional `recordID` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print(startDayDates!)` or `print(startDayDates ?? "default value")`.

But I recommend usage of `startDayList.compactMap()` instead of `startDayList.map()`to ensure your array doesn't contain nil values.

You can also do like this:

```swift
startDayList
    .compactMap { $0.created }
    .forEach { print($0) }
```

Comment: The created values is optional, that is excatly what im looking for a solution to! :D

Comment: Sorry, disregard my previous (now deleted) comment. The above code will work in your case

Comment: my func: 

`      func checkIfButtonShouldBeEnabled(startDayList: [StartDay]){
       
        let startDayDates = startDayList.compactMap{$0.created}
    
        for i in 0..<startDayDates.count {
        
            startDayList.compactMap{$0.created}.forEach{print($0)}

            
        }
        
        }` but it still prints out optional("22.01.19")

Comment: Try this `func checkIfButtonShouldBeEnabled(startDayList: [StartDay]) { startDayList.compactMap{$0.created}.forEach{print($0)} }`.

Comment: Still prints out Optional() :(